# How can I change where snap snapshots are saved?

Tags: backup, snap, raid, raspberrypi, nextcloud

Running `snap save` will compress my snap app data and save it to `/var/lib/snapd/snapshots`
I have an external RAID array that I would like my snapshots of nextcloud to be saved to (preferably by a script at regular intervals). Does snap natively allow choosing where the snapshots are saved? Either across the board or based on a command-line parameter?

Comment: I find an answer to your question in [snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/where-is-a-snap-stored-and-how-can-i-change-that/3194/4).